# How do I find out what is inserting data in my Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse

I am using an Azure 'Synapse SQL Pool' (aka Data Warehouse) containing a table named 'DimClient'. I see in my database that new records are being added every day at a specific time. I've reviewed all the ADF pipelines and triggers but none of them are set to run at that time. I don't see any stored procedures that insert or update records in this table either. I can only conclude there is another process running that is adding those records.

I turned on 'Send to Log Analytics' to forward to a workspace and included the SqlRequests and ExecRequests categories. I waited a day and reviewed the logs using the following query:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "SqlRequests" or Category  == "ExecRequests"
| where Command_s contains "DimClient" ;
```

I get 'No Results Found' but when I query the table in SSMS, it contains new records that were added within the last 24 hours. How do I determine what is inserting these records?

Answer (score 1):

you should get result. it takes time some to sync data in log analytics. also check diagnostic settings on Synpase pool